# How do I format Date/Time with jQuery Templates?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-templates

i've just started using [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) as my javascript template engine.  My question is, how can i format a date (returned from a ASP.NET Json ActionResult) in the form:

```
/Date(1288709830000)/
```

I tried doing the following:

```
{{= $.format(new Date(parseInt(comment.DateCreated.substr(6))), 'd')}}
```

Note the above uses the new jquery globalization plugin to add the `$.format` method.  Also note that `{{= comment.DateCreated }}` is long hand for saying `${comment.DateCreated}`.

I'd really appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: What do you expect?  What is actually happening?

Comment: i wouldn't recommend using jQuery or JavaScript for templating, it's just one big disaster if you ask me - try doing your templating at the MVC view/server level.

Comment: @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder - Javascript and JQuery templating is such a NON disaster that Microsoft is helping develop this kind of functionality into the CORE of JQuery.  Client side templating is awesome for bandwidth sensitive mobile development, when you are working with an API, and especially cool when your working with an external designer.

Comment: @jfar: It throws back the error "Invalid character" when it calls the buildTmplFn function inside the tmpl plugin.

Comment: @Erx: Your comment would be more constructive if you explained why you feel that way.

Comment: Javascript, JQuery and templates it's pretty much the way to go right now, it save bandwidth and allow rich ajax applications.
Just navigate on facebook, twitter, google or gmail with chrome developers tools or firebug and check XHR calls. All they do is send and receive Json objects and render that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does actually work.  I was using the beta version hosted on the Microsoft CDN.  If you download the latest version everything works as expected.

Comment: This line: {{= $.format(new Date(parseInt(comment.DateCreated.substr(6))), 'd')}}. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used

```
var formatDate = function (datetime) {
    var dateObj = new Date(parseInt(datetime.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
    return dateObj.format("dd-MMM-yyyy"); //01-Jun-2001
}
```

And this in my JQuery Template

${formatDate(InceptionDate)}

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a very hacky solution.  If you add the following function to the page:

```
function format(o, t) {
    return $.format(o, t);
}
```

You can then change the expression to:

```
{{= format(new Date(parseInt(comment.DateCreated.substr(6))), 'd') }}
```

And it works fine.  This seems strange that two plugins both created by Microsoft would conflict in this way.

Answer (score 0):

To format a datetime within a jQuery template you could write a function like:

```
function formatDate(datetime) {
    var dateObj = new Date(datetime);
    var dateStr = (dateObj.getMonth()+1) + "/" + dateObj.getDate() + "/" + dateObj.getFullYear();
    return dateStr; // will return mm/dd/yyyy
}
```

You can then call this function from within your jQuery template like so: `${formatDate(comment.DateCreated)}`

For more details see: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal