# "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" trying to display data using jquery ajax in MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm basically new to jQuery and AJAX, so I've been trying to imitate a video of someone using jQuery and AJAX in an ASP.NET MVC3 site.

I've got a model called Post which I am trying to display

```
public class Post
 {
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

This is the ActionResult function in my Controller

```
 public ActionResult GetPosts()
    {
        var posts = blogRepository.GetPosts();
        return Json(posts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

And this is my query method GetPosts:

```
 public List<Post> GetPosts()
    {
        return (from p in db.Posts
                orderby p.DateCreated descending
                select p).ToList();
    }
```

Finally, the code in my View with the script that is causing the error I posted in the title:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Body</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="blogTableBody">
</tbody>
</table>
 <script id="blogTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <tr>
      <td>${Name}</td>
      <td>${Body}</td>
      <td>${DateCreated}</td>
  </tr>
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/blog/getposts',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
           $('#blogTemplate').tmpl(result).appendTo('#blogTableBody');
        }
    });
});
</script>`
```

Basically, all I want is to show the post's Name, Body, and DateCreated in a list format in my view. So what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should work. Here's a complete example (the repository call has been replaced by hardcoded values to simplify and further isolate any problems):

Model:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetPosts()
    {
        var posts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new Post
        {
            PostId = x,
            UserId = x,
            Body = "body " + x,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            Name = "name " + x
        });
        return Json(posts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Body</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="blogTableBody">
</tbody>
</table>
<script id="blogTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr>
    <td>${Name}</td>
    <td>${Body}</td>
    <td>${DateCreated}</td>
</tr>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/getposts',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#blogTemplate').tmpl(result).appendTo('#blogTableBody');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that in my example I have used a beta version of the [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) hosted on Microsoft CDN which has some [issues with date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341518/how-do-i-format-date-time-with-jquery-templates).